# addthis.toolbox() method: buttons cut off and alt text displaying

Tags: javascript, addthis

As I'm doing some jQuery html replacement on a responsive design, it was suggested that I use the addthis.toolbox method instead of the init method from AddThis.

Even though my code is specifying the 32x32 pixel buttons they're getting displayed with the bottom half of the graphic cut off and the alt text displaying. Here's the code:

```
<div id="zazoo" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" addthis:userid="example"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="example"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_follow" addthis:userid="xx"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_youtube_follow" addthis:userid="example"></a>
</div>

<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=example&async=1">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
addthis.toolbox("#zazoo"); 
</script>
```

I even made a [stripped down version](http://www.digitalhit.com/bptest/zazoo.shtml) that's just the code and still see the issue with the cut off buttons. For the AddThis users out there...can you see a problem with the code or is a system issue on AddThis' end? I can't see any issue with the code itself, just the way it's getting displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addthis.toolbox() method only works after you've called the addthis.init() method if you're using the async flag. Change your code to this:

```
<div id="zazoo" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" addthis:userid="digitalhit"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" addthis:userid="digitalhit"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_google_follow" addthis:userid="108569913685983365364"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_youtube_follow" addthis:userid="digitalhit"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_rss_follow" addthis:userid="http://feeds.feedburner.com/DigitalHitEntertainmentNews"></a>
</div>
<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=dheian&async=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
addthis.init();
// -->
</script>
```

The addthis.toolbox() method is only used to render the buttons after the first initialization.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I thought it was an either/or proposition with the two commands. Either I didn't read the API right (need coffee) or perhaps it could be clearer. Thanks for your help.